# Displaying Bitap Splash Screen of executable-reverse engineering

Tags: reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I am going through the following learning resource http://binary-auditing.com/ and am stuck on the first exercise in the File Understanding section. In the exercise I basically have to get the GUI to display a splash screen BITMAP when a certain MenuItem is pressed. I have found the resource for the BITMAP and know it's id though I'm not sure what to do next. Should I do DLL injection or create a codecave and if so how would I go about doing this. I've been searching for material to tackle this exercise for many days though can't seem to wrap my head around it, the subsequent exercises are similar in nature.

The following is the description of the exercise:

```
All You have to do is:
Display a splash screen (it's in resource of Rev1.exe), when You click on the Bitmap menu.

NO PATCHING & PROCESSPATCHING ALLOWED!!!
There are few ways to do it so, GENTLEMEN START YOUR ENGINES!
```

I know how to read assembly and have some understanding of converting it to higher level languages though have no experience of modifying execuatable in such a manner. I also can't seem to find any tutorials or resources on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going through the binary auditing series as well, and was searching for some clarification on what the author of rev1.exe meant by no patching.  That's how I came across your question.

Anyway, you can find a great set of tutorials on binary modification and reverse engineering at [the legend of random](http://thelegendofrandom.com/blog/sample-page)

In particular, I would follow the tutorial on [Adding a Splash Screen](http://thelegendofrandom.com/blog/archives/558) although I don't know if that technique violates the no patching rule.